# Styling C# Alert Box

Tags: c#

I am very new to C#.net programming...I have a good background with Html5 and Css3 and some JavaScript...

I am trying to figure out how to style the below alert box...I have searched the net and forums...this is my first post here...haven't been able to figure it out...

Please let me know if you need anymore info...thank you...

Below is the C# Code

```
protected void IsValidNumber(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  int num;

  if (Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out num))
  {
    Response.Redirect("checkin.aspx");
  }
  else
  {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + TextBox1.Text + "');", true);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't style alert boxes. look into jQuery UI.

Comment: You shouldn't be using alert boxes to begin with.

Comment: If you want to start styling things, it's the time to start thinking about CSS and JavaScript. jQuery would make the job very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style alert boxes. Those are the property of the browser alone.

However, what you can do is create the popup using HTML and CSS inside a hidden DIV, and display it whenever you want. [Jquery makes this easy](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Thank you for the help...how would I call it though...below is the asp:textbox code that is calling the methode...I understand the div theory you mentioned...however...what would that code look like???  The C# code??

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autofocus ontextchanged="IsValidNumber"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Well it depends on your scenario. For starters, you can just do what you're doing right now. Register a startup script. Instead of an alert the script would be the JQUery javascript that shows the popup.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style alert box, The browser dictates how it should look. You would have to make your own custom box using css.

There are a lot of posts on SO on how to do this, just find a library that fits you.